# Jenkins: How to Enable a complex Jenkins Email Notifications Change Set Setup

Tags: git, email, jenkins

I am having difficulty setting up email notifications for a complex build process. Let me explain the build process and see if anyone has suggestions of how to implement this.

I have a single GIT repository, that has multiple applications that get built into their own binaries. I know this would be better to break it up but given the nature of the project that is not an option.

Something like this:

```
-root
  -Apps
    -App 1
    -App 2
```

**Results: ** App1.bin, App2.bin, etc.

Multiple teams contribute to this repository. I have 3 jenkins jobs.

1. **Build 1 binary** (Builds a single binary for deployment)
2. **Build multiple binaries** (This is a wrapper and calls the first job to be able to build multiple binaries).
3. **Auto build** (This job parses the change set in the repository and calls the build multiple binaries, with the apps to build. Reason for this, is if a SCM change occurs, I don't want to build all apps again in the repository. I want to only build the apps that changed.)

What I want to do:

I want the **Build 1 binary** to send email notifications of the change set, just for that app that got built.

Example Email:

```
Subject: App1 Successful build
Changes: App1/app1.source, App1/app1.properties
```

The problem is because **Auto build** picks up the change set from the GIT change, I don't have a way right now to find the change set in the build job. What I am thinking is parsing the change set, and passing them down the chain. Then I would just have to parse the individual file changes to send a notification for a single binary build.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions to filter the build output and send only the info you want on the email using the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin.

i.e:

${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="^App1/.*$", linesBefore=0, linesAfter=0, maxMatches=50, showTruncatedLines=false, escapeHtml=false}

This will be replaced with the lines that were matched by the regex.

Comment: This solves the filtering issue, but how can I maintain the SCM change set? Once the second build executes, that change set is lost. I would have to dump it to a temporary file, and filter out from there.

Comment: Instead of a temporary file, i believe you could use a environment variable for this. Take a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can come up with